# How can i send an email with a button click in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a little rusty with rails. I am trying to send an email with a click of a button with action mailer. I have a driver model where there is an email field. I want to have a button to send an email to the driver.email field when it is clicked. I keep getting different errors. I have tried different things and looked all over but cannot find a solution.

Errors I get:

- Cannot find driver with id = ""
- wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

I have a drivers table below is the schema.

```
create_table "drivers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "first_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.string "phone"
t.string "city"
t.string "state"
t.string "email"
t.boolean "active"
t.string "load"
t.string "status"
t.string "comments"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
```

Here is my action mailer.

```
class DriverMailer < ApplicationMailer
def send_mail
 @driver  = Driver.find.(params[:id])
 mail(to: @driver.email, subject: "You have a new load to deliver")
end
end
```

I created an action in my Drivers controller as below.

```
def send_mail 
  DriverMailer.send_mail(@driver).deliver_now
  flash[:notice] = "Email has been sent."
  redirect_to driver_path(@driver.id)
end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :drivers
   get "/send_mail" => 'drivers#send_mail'
end
```

in my index.html i have a link to where if the user clicks **Send Mail** it will send an email to the email saved on the Driver Model.

```
 <%= link_to 'Send mail', send_mail_path(@driver), class: "big-button"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I created an action in my Drivers controller as below.

wrong, it should be

```
def send_mail
  driver  = Driver.find(params[:id]) //if you're not using before action set_driver
  DriverMailer.send_mail(driver).deliver_now
  flash[:notice] = "Email has been sent."
  redirect_to driver_path(driver.id)
end
```

also, where is an argument in your mailer method definition?

```
def send_mail(driver)
  @driver = driver
  mail(to: @driver.email, subject: "You have a new load to deliver")
end
```

now your route is

```
get "/send_mail" => 'drivers#send_mail'
```

wrong, pass `:id`

```
get "/send_mail/:id" => 'drivers#send_mail', as: 'send_mail'
```

Comment: I got an undefined method as i am using before action set driver. However, i included the send_mail in that and now it works! Is it good practice to do that? here is how it looks:

`before_action :set_driver, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :send_mail]`

Comment: Yes, its look good, also i included that code because i don't know what code you have written in your controller, you just need to make changes in your mailer method